# select2 list not being populated

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm having issues populating my list using select2. This is what I got this far. No errors in the browser debugger. Just returning "no results found". Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   //The url we will send our get request to
   var attendeeUrl = '/Schedule/getCourses';
   var pageSize = 20;

$(".test").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: attendeeUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        type: 'GET',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params.term,
                size: pageSize,
                page: params.pageSize
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data.text
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
    minimumInputLength: 1
 });
});
```

Comment: use fiddler to check what exactly is returned, go <RAW> tab. Then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include the following.

```
templateResult: formatRepo,
templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
```

And the following functions.

```
function formatRepo(repo) {
   if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

   var markup = '<div class="asd">' + repo.CourseCode +
   '</div>';
   markup += '</div></div>';
   return markup;
}
function formatRepoSelection2(repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}
```